# Go server not responding properly.

Tags: go

I followed the example on Go docs and compiled this code for a Go server:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hi there, I love %s!", r.URL.Path[1:])
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

But when I access
localhost:8080 it doesn't show up anything.

Comment: Does the program stop or go on ? Try `log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))`. If there is no error, try to look for firewall problems.

Comment: Probably yours port `8080` is already in use by some other process, check `netstat` or something like that

Comment: @dystroy The program goes on but it doesn't register any requests on accessing 8080 port.

Comment: Your comment below states that there was another server running on `8080`. That should have resulted in an error. Are you saying it didn't show the error when you used @dystroy's code?

Answer (score 5):

Change `http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)`

to

```
if err := http.ListenAndServe("localhost:8080", nil); err != nil {
    log.Fatal("ListenAndServe: ", err)
}
```

This will force the server to only listen on the `localhost` interface and you won't have problems with permissions and firewall rules. It also logs any errors you may encounter.

Comment: What I proposed in my first comment was shorter for the same result.

Answer (score -1):

In linux you need permission to run the program, because it is need listen on 8080 port.
I am using Ubuntu, and I ran `go build -o main`, then I run `sudo ./main`, when I access the localhost:8080 it shows `Hi there, I love !`

Comment: I simply ran `./main` to run the server and it worked. In Firefox, `http://localhost:8080/` outputs `Hi there, I love !`. I'm running: `$ uname -a`
`Linux Peter 3.5.0-31-generic #52-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 16 16:27:05 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`.

Comment: You don't need permission to access port `8080`. Only low port numbers. I think below `1024` requires permission.

Comment: The problem was that there was another server running at 8080. Killed that and it worked fine.

Comment: Yes, You are right, I am usually using port 80, if I don't start with `sudo`, it doesn't work. so I think it need `sudo` for port 8080 also, and it works, that is what I think it need `sudo` too.